# Javascript "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" error

Tags: javascript, html

**JS output: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"**

I'm writing a simple game which has a very simple clock counter.
I'm trying to add every second to span innerHTML/innerText.

here's my code:

**HTML:**

`<span>Time: <span id="game_time";>0</span></span>`

**JS:**

```
var stopTimerId;
var timeInSeconds = 1;
var intervalSeconds = 1000;
var game_time = document.getElementById("game_time");

stopTimerId = setInterval(function () {
            parseInt(game_time.innerText) += timeInSeconds;
        }, intervalSeconds);
```

Later on I have of course

`clearInterval(stopTimerId);`

I've tried parseInt for the left side, I tried for both.
I also tried parseFloat for the left side and for both.

thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseInt(game_time.innerText) += timeInSeconds;` doesn't make sense. You can't increment an anonymous value such as the one returned from a function call here, only a variable. Otherwise, where would the result go?

You probably want this instead:

```js
game_time.innerText = parseInt(game_time.innerText) + timeInSeconds
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you that you can't assign a value to a primitive value, you can only assign to a variable or object property.

```
parseInt(game_time.innerText)
```

returns a number, a primitive value that is immutable. You can't modify it.

What you can do is assign the value to a variable, then modify that, e.g.

```
let time = parseInt(game_time.innerText);
time += timeInSeconds;
```

Comment: That wouldn't update the `game_time` element then, though.

Comment: It shows appropriate use of the [+= addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) in the context of the OP.

Comment: True but the OP clearly wants to update the text in the `game_time` HTML element to reflect the change, not just to update a new variable that is nowhere used yet. Your answer would be complete if it'd end by showing that you would then have to assign `game_time.innerText = time`.